# How to return value with no 'cannot move out of borrowed content' error?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm new to Rust and toying a bit with it. It's my first program, and it seems I've already encountered the dreaded borrow checker. :)

```
pub struct Foo<T> {
    memory:  Vec<T>
}

impl<T> Foo<T> { {
    pub fn set(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.memory.push(value);
    }

    pub fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&T> {
        Some(&self.memory[index])
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine but I want to return value not reference from get function.

If I do

```
pub fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<T> {
    Some(*&self.memory[index])
}
```

Which fails with:

`error: cannot move out of borrowed content [E0507]
  Some(*&self.memory[index])`

I just have no idea why the borrow checker behaves this way.

How can I return the value? Can anyone enlighten me?

**Rem:** It's not duplicate question. I don't ask someone explain what "indexed content" means but how to return value with no `cannot move out of borrowed content` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `clone` the object you want to return in order for that to be possible. This also means `T` needs to be `Clone`able. Consider the following code:

```
pub struct Foo<T: Clone> {
    memory: Vec<T>
}

impl<T> Foo<T> where T:Clone {
    pub fn set(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.memory.push(value);
    }

    pub fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<T> {
        Some(self.memory[index].clone())
    }
}
```

If this concerned an object that could be returned in full (unlike an element of a vector), you could create a method that moves the object, like so:

```
pub struct Foo<T> {
    memory: T
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    pub fn get(self) -> Option<T> {
        Some(self.memory)
    }
}
```

Note that this time the argument is not `&self`, but just `self`, so the ownership will be moved.

You can also consider implementing `Copy` for `T`. In this case it will be passed to functions as value instead of reference like a primitive type, e.g. `i32`:

```
pub struct Foo<T: Copy> {
    memory: Vec<T>
}

impl<T> Foo<T> where T:Copy {
    pub fn set(&mut self, value: T) {
        self.memory.push(value);
    }

    pub fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<T> {
        Some(self.memory[index].clone())
    }
}
```

I would not recomment this, however, for memory-heavy objects or those whose ownership should for any reason be preserved/secured.

Comment: Or implement `Copy`.

Comment: How can I implement `Copy` of `T`?

Comment: I added this information to the post.

Comment: Thank for your help. Following your recommendation, I realized with `clone` .